# Putting a table ontop of an image using css, html and dreamweaver

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am just starting out making my first website. 
What I am trying to do is put a chart over top of a picture. I have a tiled background image, and then I have another large image onto of the background. I want a chart to be put on top of the large image. In my CSS panel I have set the placement to where I want the chart to be (on top of the image), but when I change the position to "absolute" the chart just disappears. I think it might be behind my other picture? When I change the position to "relative" it goes where I want it to be, but of course I don't want it relative (moving with the window) I want it to be in the same place when the window changes.

I'm hoping there is a quick fix for this that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For absolute to work the element must be inside an element with its position set to relative, fixed, or absolute.

```
<div id="outer" style="position:relative">
    <div id="inner" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px">
        blah
    </div>
</div>
```

edited to remove link.   Just google "position absolute values"

Comment: please don't reference w3schools.  They are non w3c compliant and refuse to comply with w3c standards. [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Thanks Johnny I think I got it